# how to count how many cell of a column are different of empty or null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a html table with different columns and i want to check how many cells of a column i want have something ( != null or != ""), i tried different thing but nothing works

table code:

```
<table width="49%" border="1" align="left" cellspacing="0" id="table_left">
    <tr id="left_tittle">
        <td width="25%"><strong>Animal</strong>
        </td>
        <td width="25%"><strong>Hierro</strong>
        </td>
        <td width="35%"><strong>Clasificación</strong>
        </td>
        <td width="15%"><strong>Peso</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="textfield"></label> <span id="oAnimal">
        <input name="anml" type="text" id="anml1" class="col1"
        required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor entre el codigo del animal')"
        style="width:96%" align="center"/>
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Por favor entre el codigo del animal</span></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="hierro"></label> <span id="oHierro">
        <input name="hierro3" type="text" id="hierro1" 
        required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor entre el hierro del animal')"
        style="width:96%" align="center" />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Por favor entre el hierro del animal</span></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="clasificacion"></label> <span id="oCls">
        <input name="clsf" type="text" id="clsf1" 
        required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor entre la clasificacion del animal')"
        style="width:96%" align="center" />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Por favor entre la clasificacion del animal</span></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="peso"></label> <span id="oPso">
        <input name="pso" type="text" id="pso1" class="colPeso"
        required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor entre el peso del animal')"
        style="width:93%" align="center" />
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Por favor entre el peso del animal</span></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="textfield"></label>
            <input name="animal" type="text" id="anml2" class="col1" style="width:96%"
            align="center" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="hierro"></label>
            <input name="hierro" type="text" id="hierro2" style="width:96%"
            align="center" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="clasificacion"></label>
            <input name="clasificacion" type="text" id="clsf2" style="width:96%"
            align="center" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="peso"></label>
            <input name="peso" type="text" id="pso2" class="colPeso" style="width:93%"
            align="center" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="textfield"></label>
            <input name="animal" type="text" id="anml3" class="col1" style="width:96%"
            align="center" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="hierro"></label>
            <input name="hierro" type="text" id="hierro3" style="width:96%"
            align="center" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="clasificacion"></label>
            <input name="clasificacion" type="text" id="clsf3" style="width:96%"
            align="center" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="peso"></label>
            <input name="peso" type="text" id="pso3" class="colPeso" style="width:93%"
            align="center" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="textfield"></label>
            <input name="animal" type="text" id="anml4" class="col1" style="width:96%"
            align="center" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="hierro"></label>
            <input name="hierro" type="text" id="hierro4" style="width:96%"
            align="center" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="clasificacion"></label>
            <input name="clasificacion" type="text" id="clsf4" style="width:96%"
            align="center" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="peso"></label>
            <input name="peso" type="text" id="pso4" class="colPeso" style="width:93%"
            align="center" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="textfield"></label>
            <input name="animal" type="text" id="anml5" class="col1" style="width:96%"
            align="center" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="hierro"></label>
            <input name="hierro" type="text" id="hierro5" style="width:96%"
            align="center" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="clasificacion"></label>
            <input name="clasificacion" type="text" id="clsf5" style="width:96%"
            align="center" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label for="peso"></label>
            <input name="peso" type="text" id="pso5" class="colPeso" style="width:93%"
            align="center" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

my actual script

```
     $('#table_left tr:not(#left_tittle)').bind('keyup change', function () {
         var $table = $(this).closest('table');
         var total = 0;
         var count = 0;
         $table.find('.colPeso:not(#left_tittle)').each(function () {
             total += +$(this).val();
         });

         $table.find('.col1:not(#left_tittle)').each(function () {
             if ($(this).html() != null) {
                 count = count + 1;
             }
         });

         totalPesoL = total;
         console.log("numero de animalesI: " + count);
         //console.log( "total: " + total + " totalPesoL: " + totalPesoL);
         //$table.find('input[name="total"]').val(total);
     });
```

the part im trying to figure how to make it work is:

```
  $table.find('.col1:not(#left_tittle)').each(function () {
      if ($(this).html() != null) {
          count = count + 1;
      }
```

or

```
    $table.find('.col1').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != null || $(this).val() != "" || $(this).val() != " ") {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    });
```

for some reason on my console the log is always with the count variable = 20

[image]

col1 is the first column of left side of the picture, it have only 3 cell with something and the value is always 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the contents of an `input`, not the `html()` of some block element.

The test you want is:

```
if ($(this).val() != '') {
  count = count + 1;
}
```

Also, the `:not` part of your selector is unnecessary: none of the inputs have that id. So:

```
$table.find('.col1').each(
  function() {
    var v = $(this).val() || "";

    if ( v.trim() != '' ){
      count = count + 1;  
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: thanks man, alredy try that way, but for some reasson count value is always 20(the number of cells in that column), i really dont know why

Comment: It's working for me here: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/Gkuyf, logging a count of `1` as expected.

Comment: i have the code, just like i show in the question, and like the picture when i try it the console always show the count variable value on 20, i dont know why

Comment: Your code in the question is different from mine - you're checking that it doesn't equal `''`, *or* doesn't equal `null`, *or* doesn't equal `" "`. At least one of those will always be true: if it's equal to `""`, it won't be equal to `" "`, so you'll count it. Change that line to: `if ($(this).val() != null && $(this).val() != "" && $(this).val() != " ")` if you really want all of those cases checked.

Comment: Edited my code to catch `null`, or all-whitespace strings of any length.

Comment: u are right man, that was my mistake, now its working fine!! thank u!